# ImportError: Using URI string without sqlalchemy installed, while executing REGEXP function on pandas SQL API with SqlLite

Tags: python, regex, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I am trying to execute REGEXP Funtion of SqlLite using Pandas SQL API, but getting an error of

> "ImportError: Using URI string without sqlalchemy installed."ohon

The python code is as follows :

```
import pandas as pd
import csv, sqlite3
import json, re

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

print(sqlite3.version)
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)


def regexp(y, x, search=re.search):
    return 1 if search(y, x) else 0


conn.create_function("regexp", 2, regexp)
df = pd.read_json("idxData1.json", lines=True)
df.to_sql("temp_log", conn, if_exists="append", index=False)

rsDf = pd.read_sql_query(
    conn, """SELECT * from temp_log WHERE user REGEXP 'ph'""", chunksize=20,
)

for gendf in rsDf:
    for item in gendf.to_dict(orient="records"):
        print(item)
```

The error it throws is

```
   raise ImportError("Using URI string without sqlalchemy installed.")
ImportError: Using URI string without sqlalchemy installed.
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing. Please not that I have a specific requirement of using Pandas SQL API.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because you specified the parameters to [`read_sql_query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) in the wrong order. Specifically, the 1st parameter should be the query, and the connection comes second, like this:

```
rsDf = pd.read_sql_query(
    """SELECT * from temp_log WHERE user REGEXP 'ph'""", conn, chunksize=20,
)
```

Comment: Yes, for me, this was the reason!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just run the following command and install `SQLAlchemy`:

```
pip3 install SQLAlchemy
```

As @Xbel said:

> Note that the error may be raised because the order of the parameters is wrong, e.g., adding a connection first and then the SQL statement. As it seems, it was the case. Note that installing SQLAlchemy does not help.

Comment: Still occurring even with this installed.

Comment: Note that the error may be raised because the order of the parameters is wrong, e.g., adding a connexion first and then the SQL statement. As it seems, it was the case. Note that installing SQLAlchemy does not help.

Comment: @Xbel Sure you are right! The answer has been modified.